# Trying to setup a very simple Android Google Map w/ Cluster but Nothing Shows Up

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have been to make a simple, demo app to test the clustering on the Google Maps API; however, nothing seems to be showing up.  I don't know what causing it as I copied the code verbatim from Google's website.

Thanks in advance,

Jacob

```
package com.example.toshiba.jsonmap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterItem;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GoogleMap map;
    ClusterManager mClusterManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        GoogleMap map = mapFragment.getMap();
    }
    private void setUpClusterer() {
        // Declare a variable for the cluster manager.


        // Position the map.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.503186, -0.126446), 10));

        // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
        // (Activity extends context, so we can pass 'this' in the constructor.)
        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, map);

        // Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
        // manager.
        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

        // Add cluster items (markers) to the cluster manager.
        addItems();
    }

    private void addItems() {

        // Set some lat/lng coordinates to start with.
        double lat = 51.5145160;
        double lng = -0.1270060;

        // Add ten cluster items in close proximity, for purposes of this example.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            double offset = i / 60d;
            lat = lat + offset;
            lng = lng + offset;
            MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(lat, lng);
            mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
        }
    }
}


class MyItem implements ClusterItem {
    private final LatLng mPosition;

    public MyItem(double lat, double lng) {
        mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    }

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although you declare setUpClusterer, you never call it.